# httpd unpacking error on installing subversion and mod_dav_svn

Tags: svn, centos6, centos6.4, mod-dav-svn

I am unable to make subversion working on centOS 6.4. I am getting httpd unpacking error on installing mod_dav_svn. I am getting the following error.

```
Running Transaction
  Installing : subversion-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64                             1/3
  Installing : httpd-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64                            2/3
Error unpacking rpm package httpd-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64
warning: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf created as /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.rpmnew
warning: /etc/httpd/conf/magic created as /etc/httpd/conf/magic.rpmnew
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/httpd/logs: cpio: rename
  Installing : mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64                            3/3
  Verifying  : mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64                            1/3
  Verifying  : subversion-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64                             2/3
  Verifying  : httpd-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64                            3/3

Installed:
  mod_dav_svn.x86_64 0:1.6.11-9.el6_4     subversion.x86_64 0:1.6.11-9.el6_4

Failed:
  httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-29.el6.centos
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, here is the error message you gave us:

```
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/httpd/logs: cpio: rename failed - Is a directory
```

The problem is that `/etc/httpd/logs` is not supposed to be a directory. It's supposed to be a symbolic link. This is what it looks like on a live system:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 19 Aug 24 23:39 /etc/httpd/logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
```

So move the `/etc/httpd/logs` directory somewhere else, and then try running the update.

Comment: Similar issue when `/etc/httpd/modules` was not a symlink for **httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm** (removed directory, then upgrade worked)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean cache of yum

```
# yum clean all
```

and try again. Also you could try to download rpm directly from server

```
# wget http://mirror.mirohost.net/centos/6.4/updates/x86_64/Packages/httpd-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm    
# rpm -ivh httpd-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Not working :( I tried to install using rpm, got this error: 
`Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:httpd                  warning: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf created as /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.rpmnew
warning: /etc/httpd/conf/magic created as /etc/httpd/conf/magic.rpmnew
########################################### [100%]
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/httpd/logs: cpio: rename failed - Is a directory`

Comment: What is mdsum of the httpd-2.2.15-29.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm ?

Comment: Sorry Alex i didn't get you. how can i find the mdsum ? am a beginner in this.. :/

Comment: Just use md5sum command